# Showing application error after sucessfull deployment in python application

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku

I made a new Python Project in Django, then deployed the application to the Heroku. When I open my application it shows me application error message.

My logs don't indicate any errors as far as I can tell, but I'm receiving the following error when loading the site:

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command.

Below you can find the logs. Am I missing something here?

```
   (foodtasker) C:\Users\nikku\Desktop\foodtasker>heroku logs --tail
    2021-02-11T10:52:05.964281+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user nkarnwal07
    @gmail.com
    2021-02-11T10:52:05.964281+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user nkarnwal07@gm
    ail.com
    2021-02-11T10:52:06.223875+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user nkarnwal07@gma
    il.com
    2021-02-11T10:52:06.223875+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user nkarnwal07
    @gmail.com
    2021-02-11T11:10:53.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user nkarnwal07@gmai
    l.com
    2021-02-11T11:11:06.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build outp
    ut: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/8ca09b4c-2b22-4b60-9bef-ea151d6f0ace/activ
    ity/builds/96248b6d-f0dc-4016-b9bf-228f21fa2a87
    2021-02-11T11:12:31.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user nkarnwal07@gmai
    l.com
    2021-02-11T11:12:45.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build outp
    ut: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/8ca09b4c-2b22-4b60-9bef-ea151d6f0ace/activ
    ity/builds/1a7d4064-5c4a-4e6b-a40a-b937ca3b4446
    2021-02-11T11:16:22.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user nkarnwal07@gmai
    l.com
    2021-02-11T11:16:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build outp
    ut: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/8ca09b4c-2b22-4b60-9bef-ea151d6f0ace/activ
    ity/builds/482acec5-04d8-404e-a5f8-aaeaeba66ab7
    2021-02-11T11:18:33.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user nkarnwal07@gmai
    l.com
    2021-02-11T11:19:06.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build outp
    ut: https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/8ca09b4c-2b22-4b60-9bef-ea151d6f0ace/activ
    ity/builds/bb7d467e-cb82-41f6-93cc-8d355d14f52a
    2021-02-11T11:20:17.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user nkarnwal07@gmai
    l.com
    2021-02-11T11:21:02.046625+00:00 app[api]: Running release v3 commands by user n
    karnwal07@gmail.com
    2021-02-11T11:21:02.046625+00:00 app[api]: Attach DATABASE (@ref:postgresql-grac
    eful-45718) by user nkarnwal07@gmail.com
    2021-02-11T11:21:02.058325+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user nkarnwal07
    @gmail.com
    2021-02-11T11:21:02.058325+00:00 app[api]: @ref:postgresql-graceful-45718 comple
    ted provisioning, setting DATABASE_URL. by user nkarnwal07@gmail.com
    2021-02-11T11:21:02.349656+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 15cf89b5 by user nkarnwal07@gm
    ail.com
    2021-02-11T11:21:02.349656+00:00 app[api]: Release v5 created by user nkarnwal07
    @gmail.com
    2021-02-11T11:21:13.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
    2021-02-11T11:21:55.731928+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python
     manage.py migrate` by user nkarnwal07@gmail.com
    2021-02-11T11:22:00.717189+00:00 heroku[run.4368]: Awaiting client
    2021-02-11T11:22:00.740738+00:00 heroku[run.4368]: Starting process with command
     `python manage.py migrate`
    2021-02-11T11:22:00.769075+00:00 heroku[run.4368]: State changed from starting t
    o up
    2021-02-11T11:22:10.648169+00:00 heroku[run.4368]: Process exited with status 0
    2021-02-11T11:22:10.714284+00:00 heroku[run.4368]: State changed from up to comp
    lete
    2021-02-11T11:22:38.610857+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python
     manage.py createsuperuser` by user nkarnwal07@gmail.com
    2021-02-11T11:22:44.294229+00:00 heroku[run.1332]: Awaiting client
    2021-02-11T11:22:44.320506+00:00 heroku[run.1332]: Starting process with command
     `python manage.py createsuperuser`
    2021-02-11T11:22:44.322855+00:00 heroku[run.1332]: State changed from starting t
    o up
    2021-02-11T11:23:19.377468+00:00 heroku[run.1332]: Process exited with status 0
    2021-02-11T11:23:19.445119+00:00 heroku[run.1332]: State changed from up to comp
    lete
    2021-02-11T11:23:46.811737+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web
    processes running" method=GET path="/" host=warm-journey-08688.herokuapp.com req
    uest_id=707c94b9-0edc-4bbd-b1f3-7669a29f4f1f fwd="132.154.179.180" dyno= connect
    = service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2021-02-11T11:23:47.162059+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web
    processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=warm-journey-08688.heroku
    app.com request_id=fb59c120-cf1c-4e9d-9b74-af87b1cfb8a7 fwd="132.154.179.180" dy
    no= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2021-02-11T11:24:09.647298+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web
    processes running" method=GET path="/" host=warm-journey-08688.herokuapp.com req
    uest_id=fabec02a-c3c1-4177-9c75-fc5739dc21ca fwd="132.154.179.180" dyno= connect
    = service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2021-02-11T11:25:37.991626+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web
    processes running" method=GET path="/" host=warm-journey-08688.herokuapp.com req
    uest_id=860b5327-8c92-46e9-a583-bf70e560a1a0 fwd="132.154.179.180" dyno= connect
    = service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2021-02-11T11:29:08.560365+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web
    processes running" method=GET path="/" host=warm-journey-08688.herokuapp.com req
    uest_id=1cb130f9-4bb7-40e7-853a-4faae19874a1 fwd="132.154.179.180" dyno= connect
    = service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I'm confused, Locally my application works fine but on Heroku it is showing error can you please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `check your build output: http...` maybe check that or provide those logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you added the Procfile before deploying the project. The error code H14 determines that no web dynos are running.